# Removing everything between nested parentheses

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

For removing everything between parentheses, currently i use:

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE('(aaa) bbb (ccc (ddd) / eee)', "\\([^()]*\\)", "");
```

Which is incorrect, because it gives  `bbb (ccc  / eee)`, as that removes inner parentheses only.

How to remove everynting between nested parentheses? so expected result from this example is `bbb`

Comment: Regular expressions are generally not able to match nested expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Google BigQuery, this is only possible if you know your maximum number of nestings. Because it [uses re2 library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace) that [doesn't support regex recursions](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

```js
let r = /\((?:(?:\((?:[^()])*\))|(?:[^()]))*\)/g
let s = "(aaa) bbb (ccc (ddd) / eee)"
console.log(s.replace(r, ""))
```

Comment: In that case you need to use regex recursion [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19863847/8312809) but Google BigQuery uses re2 library that [doesn't support recursions](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

If you can iterate on the regular expression operation until you reach a fixed point you can do it like this:

```
repeat {
  old_string = string
  string := remove_non_nested_parens_using_regex(string)
} until (string == old_string)
```

For instance if we have

```
((a(b)) (c))x)
```

on the first iteration we remove `(b)` and `(c)`: sequences which begin with `(`, end with `)` and do not contain parentheses, matched by `\([^()]*\)`. We end up with:

```
((a) )x)
```

Then on the next iteration, `(a)` is gone:

```
( )x)
```

and after one more iteration, `( )` is gone:

```
x)
```

when we try removing more parentheses, there is no more change, and so the algorithm terminates with `x)`.